# LibreOffice writer field calculations

Tags: textfield, libreoffice, calculation, libreoffice-writer

In a LibreOffice **writer** document with a field of #temperature_farenheit. Is there a way to create a field named #temperature_celcius that would automatically calculate and insert the correct temperature?

And if this is possible, what types of fields do I use and how do I reference them for purposes of calculations.

Answer (score 6):

This can be achieved with user variables. I'll give a start-to-finish example in painful detail for clarity, and hopefully universal applicability to other cases.

1. Open a new text document.
2. Enter some text like `Water boils at °F (°C).`
3. Put the cursor before `°F` where you would normally type the number.
4. From the menus, choose Insert→Fields→More Fields…
5. Go to the Variables tab. Choose Type: User Field.
6. Below that, you'll see each User Field gets a Name and a Value. It will not appear in your document, but enter a Name for this variable we're using to store "water's boiling temperature in degrees Fahrenheit," lets say: `BoilF`
7. Enter the Value you want stored in that variable, and accordingly shown in this field in the actual document text. Here, its: `212`
8. Click the Insert button to actually add the field to your document. You should see `212` appear in the text.

You've now added the field, but also created a variable that can be used elsewhere. Now to do the math and use it elsewhere:

9. Leaving the Fields window open, put the cursor before `°C`.
10. In the Fields window, select Type: Insert Formula.
11. Below that, enter the Formula: `(BoilF-32)*5/9`
12. Click the Insert button. You should see `100` appear in the text.

Should you ever need to update a number pair, double-click the first number—that is, the User Field in your text. Example steps, using the above starting point:

13. Add to the sentence so it reads
    `Water boils at 212°F (100°C) atop Everest.`
14. It's now wrong, so double-click `212`.
15. The Edit Fields window will appear. In the Value box, enter `154.4` and click the OK button. It will do the math and both temperatures will update in the text.
    `Water boils at 154.4°F (68°C) atop Everest.`

Be mindful of variable names. If you have 20 temperatures scattered through your text, you should in turn have 20 user variables, with thoughtfully-chosen names.

Comment: There is no way to update the (BoilF) field without double-clicking it? I would like to directly edit the value. But doing so removes the field.

Comment: I don't believe so, no. Both fields are reflecting the variable, one without math, one with. The design choice they made with Writer is that the relationship is not two-directional.

Comment: @JoelReid, I think you got the above comment wrong. It is not about bi-directional editing - updating the original user field (`212` in this case) when you edit the computed value (`100` in this case). The guy just wants a more user-friendly way to update the "normal" user field without having to double-click it, i.e. without opening the `Fields` window. I think this can be done with Input fields. Other than this, great answer, thanks! Saved me a lot of work!